# Ghostscript - Red Overlay Text

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

I have a list of PDF's which need thumbnails creating of the front page.

When I run Ghostscript there is [red overlay text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucKcS.png)

Is there any way of turning this off?

I am using the following code to render the image from the PDF

```
        using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
        {
            rasterizer.GraphicsAlphaBits = 2;
            rasterizer.TextAlphaBits = 2;
            rasterizer.EPSClip = false;     
            rasterizer.Open(pdfFileLocation, _lastInstalledVersion, false);

            var imageOutputPath = Path.Combine(outPutFolder, string.Format("{0}.jpg", imageFileName));
            var pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(xDpi, yDpi, PageNumber);
            pdf2PNG.Save(imageOutputPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            Console.WriteLine("Saved " + imageOutputPath);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript won't be producing the 'red overlay text', so it must be present in your original document. Without seeing the original PDF file I can't offer any advice. Howeve, if you are creating thumbnails, I'd say don't use GraphicsAlphaBits and TextAlphaBits as that will simply create a blurred output. This is even more true when producing a JPEG as output....

FWIW you are using something like Ghostscript.NET or GhostscriptSharp, not Ghostscript.

Comment: I was using a nuget package in my console app. I have binned this off and run it direclty from the command line. This has now resolved the issue